# Return matrices of row and column indices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am sure this question must be answered somewhere else but I can't seem to find the answer.

Given a matrix M, what is the most efficient/succinct way to return two matrices respectively containing the row and column indices of the elements of M.

E.g.

```
M = [1 5 ; NaN 2]
```

and I want

```
MRow = [1 1; 2 2]
MCol = [1 2; 1 2]
```

One way would be to do

```
[MRow, MCol] = find(ones(size(M)))
MRow = reshape(MRow, size(M))
MCol = reshape(MCol, size(M))
```

But this does not seem particular succinct nor efficient.

Answer (score 3):

This essentially amounts to building a regular grid over possible values of row and column indices. It can be achieved using [`meshgrid`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), which is more effective than using `find` as it avoids building the matrix of ones and trying to "find" a result that is essentially already known.

```
M = [1 5 ; NaN 2];

[nRows, nCols] = size(M);
[MCol, MRow] = meshgrid(1:nCols, 1:nRows);
```

Comment: Using `find` in this instance would be stylistically poor code.

Comment: @MatthewGunn well yeah, true. Since you don't actually need to *find* anything... :) Clarified this in the answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):

```
[mcol, mrow] = meshgrid(1:size(M,2),1:size(M,1))
```